# LUKS encrypted disk with pop_os installed booting into initramfs

Tags: linux, ubuntu, luks, pop-os, initramfs-tools

I've purchased a new SSD and created partitions for root, home, swap and boot. I've encrypted root, home and swap using LUKS following the directions at https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/order-management-sw/10.0?topic=considerations-encrypting-data-partitions-using-luks.

Upon going through all the steps, I've installed pop_os on the partitioned SSD using the partitions I created earlier for /, /home, swap and /boot respectively.

I go to reboot and now the machine boots up with the gray pop_os background but no.login prompt. Hitting enter a few times drops me into an 'initramfs' shell. I suspect the OS isn't booting because it is encrypted. I've scoured the internet looking for a solution but to no avail.

If what is happening makes sense to you, can you please assist because it is not obvious what I should be doing to boot up my LUKS encrypted OS install.

Comment: Pop i sUbuntu so it should have an option in the installer to use LUKS+LVM without the need to create partition previously. That works.

Comment: Yes but that option is only presented with a clean install. I am opting to encrypt partitions separately as I separated root, home and swap.

Comment: For no good reason. A separated swap isn't used for many years now (it uses a swapfile instead) and separating /home is neither recommended nor it has advantages, especially when using encryption. The point being the installer knows what it's doing , newbie users typically don't.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I separated root and home to keep things modular after reading up on some best practices but I ultimately opted to follow your suggestion with the caveat that when I do back ups, I create a compressed tar ball starting at /home/user. If I wanted to get root separately, I could so so and exclude /home and some other dirs like /proc. This achieves the result that I wanted. I still have another machine with just 1 disk drive so for that, I may have to stick with my original intent as I have 1 partitioned drive with win10 and pop. A clean install would overwrite both os.